# I don't get how find function works in C++

Tags: c++, syntax, stl, compiler-errors, tree

I would like to find a specific value index in a vector.

For example

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> vec;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    vec.push_back(i);

  int n = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5);
  printf("%d\n", n);

  return 0;
}
```

I want to find '5' index in vector. but compiler said

> error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::__wrap_iter' to
>   'int'

But When I change

```
int n = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5);
```

to

```
int n = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5) - vec.begin();
```

it worked!!

why could the latter code be compiled but the former not??

please help me!!

Comment: Homework? What would make you try that specific change?

Comment: It returns an iterator, not an index. If you want an index, your second version is correct.

Comment: Maybe read [some docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

```
std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5);
```

Returns an iterator to an element with value 5.

```
std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5) - vec.begin();
```

Returns the difference between the two iterators, and since you are subtracting `vec.begin()` you get the index.

Alternatively, you could use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
std::distance(vec.begin(), find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5));
```

Answer (score 3):

`find` returns iterator, that points on element with value `5` in this case, not integer.

You should do

```
vector::iterator it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5);
if (it != vec.end())
    // some code for assign
```

Yours second variant returns index and is not same as first. Btw, it's better to use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), cause it will work with all containers, not only containers, that have random access iterator.

Answer (score 2):

It is because [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) return an **iterator** to that element not the element itself.

You need to write this:

```
vector<int>::iterator itn = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5);
```

And then to obtain the value you need to dereference `itn` (like a pointer):

```
int n = *itn;
```

Also you can use `auto itn = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5);` in order not to manually write `vector<int>::iterator`.

In the latter case when you do

```
int n = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5) - vec.begin();
```

It is okay, because `vector`'s iterator is *random-access iterator* so substraction of two iterators gives you a 'distance' between them (e.g. count of elements between them).

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two bugs in your code:

1. `std::find` returns an iterator to the found value, not the actual value.
2. The format specifier `%d` for `printf` may not match the type returned by subtracting the difference between iterators.  So if you were to apply the fix suggested by `1.`, outputting the value needs to be done correctly.

To find the index, use `std::distance`:

```
  auto n = std::distance(vec.begin(), find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5));
```

To safely print out the distance, use `cout`, not `printf`:

```
  std::cout << n;
```

Comment: What will distance return if the item is not found (find returns vec.end()) ?

Comment: Then you will get `std::distance(vec.begin(), vec.end())` which is the number of items in the vector if the item isn't found.

Comment: Ok, so one just have to be sure not to use that result as index for vector operator[], or to mean the index of that item inside the vector (as it seems to be in the OP case).

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/), `std::find()` returns an iterator (which is NOT the integer index of the found item position inside the vector.
Once you have the iterator returned by std::find, you can:

check if the item has been found inside the container:

```
auto it = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 5);
if (it != vec.end())
{
  // item found
}
```

To get the item index position from the iterator, you can use [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), which is the more generic way to calculate the difference between 2 iterators.